# Installing problem in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, 15.10

My name is Ngo Tien Dat. And, I'm a Ubuntu new-bie.
I had a problem: After installing the KDE Plasma 5, I can't install any apps anymore. Even I use terminal to install, it asked me a question (In Vietnamese interface): "WARNING: Can't authorized these packages. Do you want to install it without authorizing?" I choosed Yes but isn't successful. Please help me!
Thanks

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpdtw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you hadn't updated the repositories just yet, my Ejen Ngo (Ejen Ali fan and Ubuntu user). OH I get it - there is a command for updating the repos - 'sudo apt-get update'. You type in that command, give yourself admin privileges to update the repo and all of that should be eradicated. Hope it helped!! :)